# Azure Data Factory v2 set pipeline name dynamically using expression in Execute Pipeline activity

Tags: .net-core, azure-data-factory

Can we use expression in Execute Pipeline's 'Invoked pipeline' field?

Basically I have list of Pipeline name in SQL Database and I want to execute pipeline in ForEach activity of ADF V2. So if somehow we can set variable and might use it in Invoked Pipeline field! This field is drop down with existing pipeline name.

Answer (score 2):

Take care though, pipelines cannot have more than 40 activities, so this would limit the number of possible invoked pipelines to 20  (assuming a bare setup with 20 IF activities, and one

As per https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/includes/azure-data-factory-limits.md :

> Maximum activities per pipeline, which includes inner activities for
>   containers: 40

Answer (score 0):

Expression is diabled in the property of 'Invoked pipeline'. This field must be static value.
The reason is that this may cause a security issue, and cause an infinite loop.

To work around, you can create several **IF** activity within the **Foreach** activity, and each **IF** activity contains an **Execute Pipeline** activity, once the **IF** condition matches the pipeline name, it will go to the next step.